# how to send mail with sendgrid and google cloud function?

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, sendgrid

I'm new with Google cloud functions and Sendgrid,I'm looking for someone that can teach me how to:
->create a cloud function on google that will send an email to a mail that i choose,using Sendgrid;
->Implement it with Dialogflow
I'm having issues with the coding part because I'm new...thx everyone!

Comment: In what app you want to use email service?

Comment: I'll try to be more clear(thanks for the comment by the way);

Comment: I need to create a chatbot that is able to get some data from a random person and then send an email to this person with the summary of the conversation;I have Sendgrid to send mails and i need to use google cloud functions but i dont now how to write a function that get's the job done;

Comment: Ok, and what's your code language?

Comment: I think it's java;i need to create an index.js code for sending mail =)

Comment: Is that information from answer bellow helped you?